# Image on Paper or Real card

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, model, tensorflow-lite

Is there a way in tensorflow to destinct between object photo on paper and real object.
Goal is to block false detection of object photo on paper.

With custom trained model, no positive result for this usecase.

Can tensorflow diffrenciate between real object and photo of the object on paper

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in tensorflow to destinct between object photo on paper
> and real object. Goal is to block false detection of object photo on
> paper.

While TensorFlow, as a deep learning framework, offers tools to construct models capable of discerning between real objects and photographs of objects on paper, it's crucial to acknowledge the inherent difficulty of this task. Achieving perfect accuracy may be elusive due to the intricate nature and diverse characteristics of real-world images.

**Dataset Collection:** Gather a dataset containing images of real objects and photos of those objects printed on paper. Ensure the dataset covers a diverse range of objects and variations in printing quality, lighting conditions, backgrounds, etc.

You can also preprocess the images, including resizing them to a consistent size, normalizing pixel values, and potentially applying data augmentation techniques to increase the diversity of your dataset.

Choose or design a suitable neural network architecture for your task. Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs) are commonly used for image classification tasks. You might also consider architectures designed for fine-grained classification tasks, as differentiating between real objects and their printed photos might require recognizing subtle details.

In the training phase, divide your dataset into three subsets: training, validation, and test sets. Initiate model training using the training set, fine-tune hyperparameters based on the validation set, and assess the model's performance on the test set. Consider leveraging transfer learning, which involves initializing the model with pre-trained weights and adjusting it to your specific task through fine-tuning on your dataset.
**Deploy the model to your application and continuously monitor its performance**.